# upgrading Apache Camel 2 to 3, where did Main.setApplicationContextUri() method go?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an old codebase that uses camel 2.something. We have to upgrade to camel 3.14 for Nexus-flagged security issues. I'm going through the [Upgrade Camel 2 to 3 docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html). I see that Main moved packages, which I did, but now I'm getting an error that Main.setApplicationContextUri("camel-context.xml") is no longer a method on Main. I can't find it, nor a replacement in the upgrade docs.

What am I missing?

Also, if there's a way to do a simple camel config via beans and annotations instead of xml, I'd love a pointer to that. I'm also running into an issue parsing the camel-context.xml, so if I can get rid of that whole mess, I'd love to.

We are using Java 8 so I think the latest that works with that is Camel 3.14.6 so that's what I'm trying.

Here's our camel-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
">

<!-- ================================== -->
<!-- Define camel context -->
<!-- ================================== -->
<camel:camelContext id="camel" trace="false">
    <camel:propertyPlaceholder id="queriesConfig" location="lib/queries.properties" />
    <!-- Location for route scan -->
    <camel:package>com.blah.listener</camel:package>
</camel:camelContext>

<!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
<bean id="sqlComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="bean1" class="com.foo.OurThing" />
<bean id="bean2" class="com.bar.OtherThing" />
```

Edit: Just found [this](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/others/main.html#_camel_main_configurations). Are we supposed to convert camel-context.xml to application.properties? We also have an app-context.xml for basic Spring configuration, and there's a reference to the camel-context.xml there. I wonder if we replace camel-context.xml with application.properties, what to do with this reference? Just remove it, or change it?

Answer (score 0):

In camel 3.2 Main class that supports ApplicationContext was moved to `camel-spring-main`.

Look here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_2.html#_main_in_camel_spring